# I want to check if user is connected to network or not and how to?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to put in this kind of code is user connected to network or not. If is connected to do this then blocks or if its NOT connected to do something other, such as get data from local storage. I'm confused how to do that.

```
    getStorageWarents() {

      this.storage.ready()
        .then(() => {
          this.warrentsInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('__mydb/_ionickv/DodNalog'));
          console.log("Warrents in storage: ", this.warrentsInStorage);

        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAssignedWarrents();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllGoods();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllCancelTypes();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllDeviceTypes();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllManufacturers();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllIntereventionTypes();
        })


  }
```

Comment: You also have the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebAPI/Network_Information) for modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **`navigator`** global object.

```
getStorageWarents() {
    isOnline: boolean = navigator.onLine;

     if(isOnline){
       // code block
     } else {
       // get data from local storage
     }
 }
```

Please follow this [article](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/detecting-internet-connection-status-in-angular-application-ng-connection-service-1fa8add3b975)

You can also use **ng-connection-service**

`import { ConnectionService } from 'ng-connection-service';`

```
  isOnline:boolean;
  isConnected = true;

  constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(isConnected => {
      this.isConnected = isConnected;
      if (this.isConnected) {
        this.isOnline = true;
      }
      else {
        this.isOnline = false;
      }
    })
  }


getStorageWarents() {

     if(this.isOnline){
       // code block
     } else {
       // get data from local storage
     }
 }
```

Comment: and how to implement them into this my code and how to do else if not connected ? Thanks

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check

Comment: please look at this code for ion-refresher while internet is ON or OFF. http://dpaste.com/2KK9RH9  it didnt work fine. When i disconnect my net and plug net cable...this function also did ELSE statement. Whats wrong ?